# Replacing dollar sign from input field onload

Tags: javascript, replace, onload

I'm trying to replace the value of an input field on load, specifically to remove the dollar sign. Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload='document.getElementById("amount")value.str.replace("$","")';
</script>
```

Comment: the most obvious issue is there is no `.` between `getElementById("amount")` and `value`.

Comment: window.onload expects a function not a string.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the period before `value` and `str` is not needed, and a function is required.

```
window.onload= function() {
    document.getElementById("amount").value = document.getElementById("amount").value.replace("$",""); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to replace dollar from the string and then you need to assign it back to DOM. *Only replacing the dollar will not help*

**Javascript**

```
function fnRemoveDollar()
{
document.getElementById("amount").value = document.getElementById("amount").value.replace("$","");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body onload="fnRemoveDollar()">
```

Tested code.